# How do I migrate an Android Studio Application .apk from API Level 18 to API Level 28?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, google-play, android-api-levels

I am attempting to republish an open source app that was created in Android Studio with an API of 18 in Android 4.3. When I attempt to publish the .apk on Google Play, I get an error that says "Change your app's target API level to at least 28." I have found information on this topic [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Is there a way to test the app in Android Studio to see where I need to alter the code to bring it up to the current API requirement?

The information displayed in the link gives little detail on how to update an API in Android Studio. It seems as though I would only need to change small details. [This](https://github.com/godstale/retrowatch/wiki/%22How-To:-Make-your-own-smart-watch%22) is the link to the source code, any information is apprecited.

Comment: Yikes, it looks like the app hasn't been touched in 5 years, and doesn't even have a gradle file, which means it wasn't created using Android Studio. You can see if the latest Android Studio will "import" this project from just the source code, which should make it generate a gradle file, where you can change the target API level.

Comment: However, bumping the API level will probably be the least of your issues in trying to bring this app up to date. Android code rots very, very quickly.

Comment: @Dmitry Brant It is a relief to know that programmers were going that hard in 2013. I wish I would have been into Microelectronics sooner. Yeah, no Gradle file. I wonder what it was created in. Thats what I need to do then: "import" the project from the source code, and instantaneously generate a Gradle file, and then change the target API. Any instruction?

Comment: @Dmitry Brant Thats a sad, sad, song. I had no idea. Perhaps as a next step, I can read and understand the framework, then attempt to publish something like it on my own. Quite the task.